# How do I get the size of a QMainWindow object?

Tags: pyqt5

I am wanting to develop a screensaver from my python project, but in order to properly fullscreen it, I need to get the size of the window. This is because I need to set a QOpenGLWidget's size accordingly. Is there a way to do this, or do I need to use a layout? If a layout is the way to go, which one do I use?

Windows 10
Python 3.7.5
PyQt5

Comment: I don't understand. If it's a screensaver it should go to fullscreen, so the size of the window will be that of the screen, no?

Comment: Yes. I want this to be usable on multiple PCs, though.

Comment: @AwesomeCronk Do you want to know the size of the window or screen?

Comment: @eyllanesc In theory, once showFullScreen() is called, the window is sized to that of the screen and the window bar at the top is hidden. I think either one will solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of visual elements are returned by method `size()`. For getting screens, there method `screens()` in `QApplication`. Check your current library version's documentation for details.

Comment: I will give this a shot when I get home!

Comment: My final result was this: self.screen().size().width() and height accordingly for the size of the QOpenGLWidget, gluPerspective, and resizeGL. Thanks!